How to integrate keycloak 25 with wildfly 22
I have already integrated my wildfly project with keycloak 13 but now I want to integrate the same project to keycloak 25 , I'm not getting what are all the configuration changes I need to do , can some one please explain me what are the changes I need to do .
I have tried creating client and mapping roles and connecting that with my current wildfly but its not working.
